# Querying Bigtable to scan rowkey from Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

Using BigQuery's Bigtable external data source, I'd like to scan rowkeys in Bigtable.

Here is BigTable schema which is similar to the official document`s time series one.

`EXCHANGE + SYMBOL + DATE (for example, NASDAQ#ZXZZT#2020-02-01`

I`d like to know how to query all data between 2020-01-01 to 2020-02-01.

I tried this way but it does not work...
`SELECT rowkey from blah.blah where rowkey >= "2020-01-01" AND rowkey <= "2020-02-01"`

Answer (score 1):

I found out the query by myself... but not sure is it a good or a bad query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT
  (SELECT keys FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rowkey, "|")) as keys WITH OFFSET AS offset WHERE offset = 0) as exchange,
  (SELECT keys FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rowkey, "|")) as keys WITH OFFSET AS offset WHERE offset = 1) as symbol,
  (SELECT keys FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rowkey, "|")) as keys WITH OFFSET AS offset WHERE offset = 2) as biz_date,
FROM
  `blah.blah`)
WHERE biz_date < '2020-01-01' AND ccy = 'SGD'
```